# ExtJS 6 - Missing CSS Statements after compilation

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6, extjs6-classic

**Enviroment**

I have an extjs 6 application which is already compiled and the css files like they should be. This application wasn't compiled for a while and now it's generating a different (wrong) css file. Since someone else changed the app, I have no clue what has changed since the last compilation. I compile with `sencha app build development` and the following CSS files change:

- build\development\MyApp\classic\resources\MyApp-all_1.css
- build\development\MyApp\classic\resources\MyApp-all_2.css

There are a few more files in the folder which do not change.
Versions:

- Sencha Cmd 6.1.3.42
- SDK Version (if neccessary) 6.0.2.407

**Problem**

I want to generate the same css like before. It seems there are just a few files which are not included within the compilation process, like:

- ext/classic/theme-base/sass/etc/mixins/frame.scss
- ext/classic/theme-base/sass/etc/mixins/slicer.scss
- ext/classic/theme-neutral/sass/src/tab/Tab.scss

**Question**

What do I have to do, to get the old css? Is there some file with includes? Like `classic\sass\src\view\main\Main.scss` or something? I guess those includes are somewhere (since it already worked at least once) and maybe commented out or something.

**What I've already tried**
I tried to compile with different themes refered by the `app.json` attribute was `builds->theme`. I also tried a lot of playing around stuff, which I can't describe here in detail.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

If you have any questions leave a comment and I'll try to add it to my text!

Comment: Have you by any chance updated Cmd in the meantime? If yes, you should try to downgrade back to 6.0.2 and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: The required SASS files are calculated based on javascript includes and theme hierarchy. If you require `ext/src/tab/Tab.js` somewhere in your application, Cmd should automatically include `sass/src/tab/Tab.scss` from all themes in your branch of the theme tree, starting with the one at the root (e.g. if you have selected Triton, that would be Base, Neutral, Neptune and Triton).